# React Native: Navigate to new screen and pass prop to Redux using onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, es6-promise, react-navigation

I am trying to pass a prop to the Redux store as well as navigate to a new screen using one onPress function. When the button is pressed, the screen correctly navigates but the Redux reducer isn't firing off.

```
<Components.ChampagneButton
  onPress = {() => this.saveTypeAndGoToNextScreen(type)}
/>

saveTypeAndGoToNextScreen = type => {
  this.saveType(type)
  this.submit()
}

saveType = type =>
  this.props.onChange({
    type
  })

submit = () =>
  helpers.goToScreen('NewJobInfo', this.props)

export default helpers.connectToRedux(
  state => ({job: state.newJob}),
  dispatch => ({onChange: job => dispatch(actions.buildNewJob(job))})
)(NewJobType)
```

My goal is to have the prop be passed to the Redux store and THEN navigate to the next screen.

Update: The code above has been updated and is now a working solution.

Comment: Why does `saveType` returns a function? Shouldn't it just execute `this.props.onChage`?

Comment: Good catch! I made the change and it worked, thank you!